# mongodb native_parser in nodejs driver 2.x

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When connecting to mongo, I have always used the recommended way

```js
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject', { native_parser: true}, (err, r) => { ... })
```

I am updating to version 2.1 of the node-mongodb-native driver.

According to the main page http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/whats-new/, a new JS-BSON parser has been introduced that supplants the C++ extension. Does this mean the `{ native_parser: true }` option is no longer needed?

Answer (score 1):

Per the source code of [`MongoClient.connect`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/lib_mongo_client.js.html) version 2.0

```
var _setNativeParser = function(db_options) {
  if(typeof db_options.native_parser == 'boolean') return db_options.native_parser;
  try {
    require('mongodb-core').BSON.BSONNative.BSON;
    return true;
  } catch(err) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

The `{ native_parser: true}` could be used in the `MongoClient.connect` function as one option parameter.